# \csvreader combined with pagestyle

Tags: header-footer

I am trying to print tests for 1200 students, each of them with their name and some other information in the heading and watermark. Therefore I must combine a loop a csvreader command and the pagestyle. But I can not make it work, it always reads the last row of the table and not the value of the loop itself.

P.S. The fancy pagestyle works well with the counter of a loop! Here is my code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{public}
\newcounter{ct}

\forloop{ct}{0}{\value{ct} < 8 }%
{ %
\addtocounter{public}{1}
\csvreader[no head, filter equal = {\thecsvinputline}{\arabic{public}} ]{Lista.csv}{}
{\pagestyle{fancy}
%
\rhead{} 
\chead{}
\lhead{\LARGE\textbf{\csvcoli-\csvcoliii}\normalsize }
\SetWatermarkText{ \shortstack{ \small \arabic{public} \\  \csvcoli } }
%\SetWatermarkColor[RGB]{210,217,242}
\SetWatermarkScale{25}
\SetWatermarkAngle{0}
\SetWatermarkLightness{0.9}
\input{\csvcolii}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please give us a dummy `Lista.csv` to be able to test your code.  Change names to Name1, etc.